# Get value of a vtkintarray by the field name

Tags: python, csv, vtk, paraview, rgbcolor

I have a `Paraview programmable filter` written in python, that I am running on a table of points to assign RGB colors as `UnsignedCharArray`. I'm just stuck in one part of the code to get the value of R, G, B fields in the range. Here is the table example:

[image: xyz table]

and here is the sample code:

```
ids = self.GetInput()
ods = self.GetOutput()

ocolors = vtk.vtkUnsignedCharArray()
ocolors.SetName("colors")
ocolors.SetNumberOfComponents(3)
ocolors.SetNumberOfTuples(ids.GetNumberOfPoints())

inArray = ids.GetPointData().GetArray(0)
for x in range(0, ids.GetNumberOfPoints()):
  rF = inArray.GetValue(x) # here I need something like GetValue(x, "R")
  gF = inArray.GetValue(x) # here I need something like GetValue(x, "G")
  bF = inArray.GetValue(x) # here I need something like GetValue(x, "B")

  ocolors.SetTuple3(x, rF,gF,bF)

ods.GetPointData().AddArray(ocolors)
```

Does anyone know how I can handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the correct way to do it:

```
ids = self.GetInput()
ods = self.GetOutput()

ocolors = vtk.vtkUnsignedCharArray()
ocolors.SetName("colors")
ocolors.SetNumberOfComponents(3)
ocolors.SetNumberOfTuples(ids.GetNumberOfPoints())

inArray = ids.GetPointData().GetArray(0)

r = ids.GetPointData().GetArray("R")
g = ids.GetPointData().GetArray("G")
b = ids.GetPointData().GetArray("B")
for x in range(0, ids.GetNumberOfPoints()):
  rF = r.GetValue(x) 
  gF = g.GetValue(x) 
  bF = b.GetValue(x) 

  # if rgb are between 0-1
  #rC = rF*256
  #gC = gF*256
  #bC = bF*256

  ocolors.SetTuple3(x, rF,gF,bF)

ods.GetPointData().AddArray(ocolors)
```

Comment: great example !